# Expression Encoder 4 , Silverlight Streaming Video Player template problem in Fullscreen mode

Tags: silverlight-4.0, video-streaming, fullscreen, expression-encoder

In Expresson player when showing a video with 4:3 aspect ratio the full screen video image crops of some of the picture at the bottom, and inserts a black bar at the top. What part of the code should I change to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, I have listed how to fix it with Expression Blend here:

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/encoder/thread/e58270bf-e101-4a13-ab8c-e7b3b7dbc2a9